# Parse tab delimited text file

Tags: batch-file, dos, file-processing

I need to parse a tab-delimited text file by grabbing specific columns, like columns 1 and 5, and output each of these columns into a text file. Please find an example of the data file, and the code:

Data file:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
123  345  678  890  012  234
234  456  787  901  123  345
etc
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off & setlocal 
For /F "tokens=1,5*" %%i in (myFile.dat) do call :doSomething "%%i" "%%j"
goto :eof 

:doSomething 
Set VAR1=%1
Set VAR2=%2
@echo %VAR1%>>Entity.txt
@echo %VAR2%>>Account.txt
```

This works, however, the `For` loop stops on the first line.

Could you help me in finding the issue?

Comment: Can you run your script from the command prompt? Can you see any error messages when you do?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine for me, but maybe try this shortened version?

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,5*" %%i in (myFile.dat) do (
echo %%i >>Entity.txt
echo %%j >>Account.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend using the shortened version by Bali C, the reason the code above **might** be stopping after the first line is because the `goto :eof` or `exit` command is not at the end of the `:doSomething` function.

```
@echo off & setlocal 
For /F "tokens=1,5*" %%i in (myFile.dat) do call :doSomething "%%i" "%%j"
goto :eof 

:doSomething 
Set VAR1=%1
Set VAR2=%2
@echo %VAR1%>>Entity.txt
@echo %VAR2%>>Account.txt
goto :eof
```

Or if Extensions are disabled, it would be outputting the following error message:

```
/F was unexpected at this time.
```

To resolve this add `EnableExtensions` to your `setlocal` command.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableExtensions
```

Comment: exactly! goto:eof is missing

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, check the output below.

**Account.txt**

"COL5"

"012"

"123"

""

**Entity.txt**

"COL1"

"123"

"234"

"etc"